# How can I make two cutting lines close to each other?

Tags: line-breaking

I was wondering how I could make two cutting lines which are close to another. This is needed to illustrate invalid deductive conclusions. I tried using `\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}` two times but there is too much space between the lines and I would need them close to another, like `=`, but they should fill a whole line. Any suggestions?

Edit: For better understanding.

What I need:

```
Premise 1: Everyday the sun sets in the east.
==================================================
Conclusion: Tommorow the sun will set in  the east.
```

(Note - there should be no disruption somewhere between the lines, `=` just happens to be the closest to look like what I need.

What I tried:

```
 Premise 1: Everyday the sun sets in the east.\newline
 \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}\newline
 \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.1pt}
 Conclusion: Tommorow the sun will set in  the east.
```

What it looks like:

```
 Premise 1: Everyday the sun sets in the east.
 ______________________________________________
 ______________________________________________
 Conclusion: Tommorow the sun will set in  the east.
```

Comment: Can you give us a proper example of what you have tried?  Minimal-but-compilable please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\rule` is a horizontal box so will be spaced like a line of text, you can use `\hrule` here.

```
 Premise 1: Everyday the sun sets in the east.

\hrule
\vspace{2pt}
\hrule

Conclusion
```

Comment: This is already really good, thanks. It's just that the conclusion now has an indent somehow. And the lower line is on the same height as the top of the line below. This is how it looks now: http://prntscr.com/d100px

Comment: @Yíu  oh you can use `\noindent conclusion` and add other `\vspace` before or after either rule.

Answer (score 5):

A short command `\addtwolines` can be handy if you repeat that a lot. See this example (the values `6pt` and `2pt` can be adjusted to your liking):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\addtwolines}{%
    \addvspace{6pt}
    \hrule\vspace{2pt}\hrule
    \addvspace{6pt}
}

\noindent Premise 1: Everyday the sun sets in the east.

\addtwolines

\noindent Conclusion: Tomorrow the sun will set in  the east.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice feature and this also works. It's a shame that I can only mark one answer as correct :( Thanks!